# Write a postgresql query that returns a list of name beginning with 'sa' and ends with 's'

Tags: database, postgresql, where-clause

The question is:

List all the cities and their district and country name if the city name begins with the letters 'Sa' and ends with 's'. Order by city name.

The part I don't know how to do is "city name begins with the letters 'Sa' and ends with 's'."

This is what I have:

```
SELECT ci.name AS city, ci. district, c.name AS country
FROM lab2.city ci INNER JOIN lab2.country c                    
ON (ci.country_code = c.country_code)
WHERE ci.name ~^ 'Sa' <----------------------This is the problem line. 
ORDER BY ci.name ASC;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and congratulations on your first question. When you get a response which answers your question, you should click the "Accepted" button (which looks like a check mark) to flag it as such, so that others aren't still looking for solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question sounds like it is searching for a pattern. In this case, you can use `LIKE`.

```
SELECT   ci.name AS city, 
         ci.district, 
         c.name AS country
FROM     lab2.city ci 
         INNER JOIN lab2.country c
            ON ci.country_code = c.country_code
WHERE    ci.name LIKE 'Sa%s' 
ORDER    BY ci.name ASC;
```

Comment: Depending on your preferences you could also say `WHERE ci.name ~ '^Sa.*s$'`; this is exactly the same as the `LIKE` clause shown. It's strictly a matter of which you prefer.

Comment: @kgrittn my answer is for general sql. is `WHERE ci.name ~ '^Sa.*s$'` exclusive for postgresql?

Comment: I would have to check the standard document to be sure (and I only look at that if I *really* have to), but my guess is that `LIKE` is more portable. I think that support for regular expressions like that is a PostgreSQL extension. I only pointed it out because the question was flagged with [tag:postgresql].